# C++ finding the instantiated templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have just discovered the following jewel in the code (the example is very simplified, but the logic is the same):

```
template <class T>
class garbage_bin
{
private:
    garbage_bin<T>(void)
    {
    }
   static garbage_bin<T>* pinstance;
public:
   static garbage_bin<T>& instance()
   {
       if(pinstance == NULL)
       {
           pinstance = new garbage_bin<T>();
       }

       return *pinstance;
   }

   void empty()
   {
       for(size_t i=0; i<items.size(); i++)
       {
           free (items[i]);
       }
   }

   void throwIn(T item)
   {
       items.push_back(item);
   }

   vector<T> items;
};
```

and then somewhere in the code (this is just ONE example ... there are thousands like this):

```
char* r = strdup(src);
garbage_bin<char*>::instance().throwIn(r);
```

and later somewhere in the code, right before the exit ...

```
garbage_bin<char*>::instance().empty();
garbage_bin<molecules*>::instance().empty();
garbage_bin<CDatabaseUsers*>::instance().empty();
```

and so on ...

so as we can see, this implements a garbage bin class, in which you can "throw in" all kind of objects, and at a later stage to avoid the memory leaks you "empty" the garbage bin. But here comes the big bottleneck: In order for this to work properly, you need to know all the classes for which this garbage bin was instantiated in order to empty them...

The most direct solution I was thinking of is to create a map of `typeid` calls for the instantiations, and assign the `garbage_bin<T>::instance()` to the name however an ancient compiler decided that he does not like this approach.

Obviously, I can make a search through the code to find all the templatizations, but I'm wondering ... is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Replacing manual deletion with manual garbage collection? That's pure genius.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Pioneered by the Windows 95 desktop :-)

Comment: A simple type-erasing registry should do the trick.

Comment: For a start, the code should _not_ be `free`ing vector elements. So it's already horribly broken. What's wrong with `items.clear()`? And do you actually need that at all? If so then, yes, a registry.

Comment: @all: Yupp... this was a piece of software written in a pure C dialect for a few years... then someone discovered C++ and decided that he does not want to track the memory allocations anymore and decided to throw in this class :) amazing ... there is NO `new` in the entire codebase, but methods like: `new_string`, `allocate_memory` ... and all these use `calloc`, `malloc` ... :) and obviously a garbage bin :)

Comment: RAII isn't popular anymore?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The elements are pointers to things which do need deallocating. But it looks like a horrible mixture of things created by `malloc` (in the first example) and things probably created with `new`, so the brokenness is probably too ingrained to do anything about short of refactoring with napalm.

Comment: Since the bin itself is leaked, shouldn't there be a bin to put that in? But then, how would you get rid of that bin?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Okay but _why_ are the elements pointers?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So whatever they point to can be deallocated when you empty the bin. As long as it came from `malloc`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes, very good

Answer (score 1):

Garbage bin bin!

```
class garbage_bin_base;

class garbage_bin_bin {
public:
    void throwIn(garbage_bin_base* rubbish) { items.push_back(rubbish); }
    void empty() { for (auto item: items) item->empty(); }
private:
    vector<garbage_bin_base*> items;
};

class garbage_bin_base {
public:
    virtual empty() = 0;
    garbage_bin_base() { garbage_bin_bin::instance().throwIn(this); }
};

template <typename T>
class garbage_bin : public garbage_bin_base {
};
```

Comment: Almost. The ownership of things is not clear though.

Comment: The ownership of things was not clear long before any of us saw this.  :)

Comment: Okay but a destructor or two might help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a registry for things to be deleted:

```
Registry registry;

// ...

if (pinstance == NULL)
{
     pinstance = new garbage_bin<T>();
     registry.add<T>();
}

// ...

registry.clear_all();
```

For example:

```
class Registry
{
     struct Base
     { 
         virtual ~Base() {}
         virtual void clear() = 0;
     };

     template <typename T> struct Derived : Base
     {
         virtual void clear() { garbage_bin<T*>::instance().empty(); }
     };

     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> targets;

public:
     void clear_all() { for (auto & p : targets) { p->clear(); } }

     template <typename T> void add()
     {
          targets.emplace_back(new Derived<T>);
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather replace `garbage_bin<T>` with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` (or, maybe, `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>`).

If you want to restrict the interface, then reimplement `garbage_bin<T>` as a wrapper around `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`. In this way, you probably don't need the `empty` method since the destructors of `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` will clean-up after themselves. However, if you want to empty the bin before destruction, then implement `empty` just calling `std::vector::clear`.

I understand that this is not exactly the simplest thing to do (because the OP says there are "thousands" of places to be changed) but a refactoring of this bad design is clearly needed.